# Individual Group Details in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I can't figure out how to make multiple groups being that each group has its own details.

Example:

```
Group A Header
Details
Group A Footer

Group B Header
Details
Group B Footer

Group C Header
Details
Group C Footer
```

Comment: are you want to make multiple groups...?

Comment: How is this different from a normal group/detail report?

Comment: Yes I want to make multiple groups

Comment: single group is easier because you can add the group detail in the report detail section but when it comes to multiple group and suppose you add multiple detail sections then how we map each group with its detail sections

Answer (score 1):

A normal crystal report not behave as you have mentioned in your example.

if you want to achieved this thing you have to create sub reports for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Crystal reports, I have tried achieving this only by building a separate report and then adding them each other as subreport.

For example : 
This will be report1.rpt
Group A Header
Details
Group A Footer

the following will be report2.rpt
Group B Header
Details
Group B Footer

the following will be in report3.rpt
Group C Header
Details
Group C Footer

No open report3.rpt and using section expert add two Page headers (PH 1, PH2) and in each on of them insert report1.rpt and report2.rpt to them respectively.

Hope I have answered your question. If yes please mark it as answered.

Cheers,
Chandra.

Answer (score 0):

More information, please.  This looks like a regular group/details report.

```
Class,  Student,     Grade
A,      Joe Hines,     A+
B,      Sarah Nyg,     A
A,      Jim Bear,      C
C,      Alice Tny,     B
A,      Manny Dear,    C
C,      DJoe Blank,    F
B,      George Blat,   B
B,      Carla Osa,     C+
B,      Wally Num,     A
```

Grouping on Class, and putting Student and Grade in the details, you will get:

```
Class A
    Jim Bear      C
    Joe Hines     A+
Students: 2

Class B
    George Blat   B
    Carla Osa     C+
    Wally Num     A
    Sarah Nyg     A
Students: 4

Class C
    Alice Tny     B
    DJoe Blank    F
Students: 2

Total Students: 8
```